# What kind of mantras and spiritual rites did Krishna do?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Did Krishna do offerings and meditations on Shiva, I know he did extensive deep meditations, were there any specific teqnuques or rituals he used, during the mahabharata or as described in puranas.